# SQL Server 2012 : query for finding Minimum and Maximum time based on the group and time window

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with date and time data like below.

[image: Employee/Section/Date time Details]

I want to collect the data of employee/section/date/time window wise min and max date/time which are bold in the above table. Below table is the result that I want to derive from the above table.

[image: Expected Query Result]

Is there any SQL query options are available to get this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min,`max`and`group by` functions for your desired result:

```
select EmpId,Section,min(EntryTime)MinEntryTime,Max(EntryTime)MaxEntryTime
from yourtable
group by EmpId,Section
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But your query will return one MIN and MAX time for one empid and one sectionid. But check the result table. I need two CLASSA MIN and MAX Time. ie. In First time window which section and its times, then second time window which section and its time, then third time window, section may be first one or new and its times. hope you understand the problem clearly. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have any batch Column?

Comment: No. There is no batch kind of columns